# Overflow and Ellipsis do not work in IE for this table

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

FF v14 has the look I am seeking.  IE9 does not hide overflow nor does it show the ellipsis.  How can I fix this to work in IE9?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .col
    {
        max-width:10em;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;
    }
    .row
    {

    }
    .table
    {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="table">
    <tr class="row">
        <td class="col">This is some text in row 1 column 1</td>
        <td class="col">This is what it looks like in row 1 column 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td class="col">here is row 2 column 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**
I noticed a validation error in visual studio:

```
Validation (CSS 2.1): 'text-overflow' is not a known CSS property name.
```

Does this mean I need to somehow explicitly specify a higher version of CSS?  If yes, how?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smacky311/zrRYq/)

Comment: Is it going into quirks mode or compatibility mode?

Comment: According to the JS command: `javascript:window.alert('You are in ' + (document.compatMode==='CSS1Compat'?'Standards':'Quirks') + ' mode.')
` I am in standards mode in IE.

Comment: Just to make sure, use the F12 developer tools instead. It'll tell you the standards and browser mode up in the top right corner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution that I think of is to wrap the contents of the cells in DIVs:

```
        <td><div class="col">This is some text in row 1 column 1</div></td>
```

A bit messy, but it does seem to work in IE, Chrome, FF and Safari.

Comment: This did not work for me.  If you feel that I did something incorrectly please modify the fiddle as proof.

Comment: +1 Nice fix. `text-overflow : ellipsis;
-ms-text-overflow : ellipsis;
-o-text-overflow : ellipsis;`